# Intent filter for specific apps

Tags: android

I want to filter intents, as receiver app, only coming from a specific app(e.g. facebook).
Data-types are video-urls.

How to do this?

This filters in the manifest file doesn't give the wanted results

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <!--<data android:mimeType="text/*" />-->
       <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not supported, on a couple of levels.

First, there is no means with any `<intent-filter>` to filter on what app creates the `Intent` that is being matched against that filter.

Second, `ACTION_SEND` does not use the `data` facet of the `Intent` — the content (such as a URL) goes in an `Intent` extra. Hence, the `<data>` element in an `<intent-filter>` cannot be used to filter on the URL. With `ACTION_VIEW`, since the URL comes in the `data` facet of the `Intent`, you can use `<data>` to restrict the supported URLs (e.g., must be from some specific host).